# Django aggregation escapes unicode strings?

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-aggregation

I tried to use aggregation on a database with unicode texts and it showed unicode object with unicode characters encoded another time. What can I do to show the unicode text after aggregation?

```
>>> from apps.person.models import Person
>>> from django.db.models import Min
>>> for p in Person.objects.all()[:1]: print(p.full_name)
...
15 чоловік
>>> Person.objects.aggregate(Min('full_name'))
{'full_name__min': u'15 \u0447\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0456\u043a'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing specific to aggregation here. In the first line, you are calling `print`, but in the second you are just letting the shell output the result of the aggregate call, which always uses the `repr` format. This would work:

```
result = Person.objects.aggregate(Min('full_name'))
print result['full_name__min']
```